# Allow Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance to write file to Google Storage Bucket - Python

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

In my python server script which is running on a google cloud VM instance, it tries to save an image(jpeg) in the storage. But it throws following error.

> File "/home/thamindudj_16/server/object_detection/object_detector.py",
>   line 109, in detect Hand
>       new_img.save("slicedhand/{}#sliced_image{}.jpeg".format(threadname,
>   i))   File
>
> "/home/thamindudj_16/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py",
>   line 2004, in  save
>       fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
>
> OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'slicedhand/thread_1#sliced_image0.jpeg'

All the files including python scripts are in a **google storage bucket** and have mounted to the VM instance **using gcsfuse**. App tries to save new image in the **slicedhand** folder.

Python code snippet where image saving happen.

```
from PIL import Image

...
...

i = 0
new_img = Image.fromarray(bounding_box_img)      ## conversion to an image
new_img.save("slicedhand/{}#sliced_image{}.jpeg".format(threadname, i))
```

I think may be the problem is with permission access. Doc says to use `--key_file`. But what is the key file I should use and where I can find that. I'm not clear whether this is the problem or something else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are using [gcfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) on your Linux VM Instance to access Google Cloud Storage.

Key file is a Service Account credentials key, that will allow you to initiate Cloud SDK or Client Library as another Service Account. [You can download  key file from Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-console). However, if you are using VM Instance, you are automatically using Compute Engine Default Service Account. You can check it using console command: `$ gcloud init`.

To [configure properly your credentials, please follow the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md).

Compute Engine Default Service Account, need to have [enabled Access Scope **Storage > Full**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes). Access Scope is the mechanism that limits access level to Cloud APIs. That can be done during machine creation or when VM Instance is stopped.

Please note that [Access Scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts?hl=en_US&_ga=2.50969513.-125532137.1551689756#accesscopesiam) are defined explicitly for the Service Account that you select for VM Instance.

> Cloud Storage [objects names have requirements](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#objectnames). It is strongly recommended avoid using hash symbol "#" in the names of the objects.

Comment: Yeah. I figured out that I'm using Default Service Account. Most probably my problem will be with 'gcsfuse by default shows all files as owned by the invoking user. Therefore you should invoke gcsfuse as the user that will be using the file system, not as root'.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. This is regarding my university project. Since I don't have much time, I did save images to the virtual machine memory instead of bucket. Currently I don't have much time to try. But if I try, I will let you know. Referred document seems to be helpful. Thank you for your time.